# open link from iframe in new tab in Opera and Chrome

Tags: html, css, iframe, href, target

I have big trouble to open a links from my iframe in new tab in Opera and chrome. I have tried target ="_blank", but it works only in IE. Can anzone pleaaase help me?

Here is example of the link:

```
  <a href="http://www.webpage.sk/" target="_blank"> DESCRIPTION</a>
```

Comment: also from iframe? do you have that link inside a iframe please?

Comment: Does that iframe have the HTML5 `sandbox` attribute set by any chance …? (And if so, to what value?)

Answer (score 0):

It worked correctly in chrome.

Check out the demo http://jsfiddle.net/TYw5e/1

JsFiddle shows the result in a `iframe`.

The problem lies somewhere.